# Do a combine subscribe on two different Mono in reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have two Mono

```
Mono<Profile> profile;
Mono<Account> account;
```

**Profile.java**

```
public class Profile{
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

**Account.java**

```
public class Account{
    int id;
    String password;
}
```

I have a service class which saves these two mono into couchbase.
The save function of service class returns Mono.
Is there a way where I can save these two Mono into database at a time with one subscriber itself.

something like this...

```
createService.save(profile)..useOfSomeFunction..createService.save(account).subscribe();
```

In this way I can save both the documents at a time with just one subscriber.

Can somebody please help on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If you want:

- to save both at the same time but don't care about the return value use `Mono.when(save(account), save(profile))`
- to save one after the other, use `save(account).then(save(profile))` (you'll only see the result of the second call)
- to save both at the same time AND do something with the results, use `Mono.zip(save(account), save(profile), (acc, prof) -> doSomething(...))`